# How to add context.xml file to embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm trying to run my application in an embedded tomcat server using Spring-boot. I'm having my JNDI Resources and Environments configured in an XML file, placed under src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml in my application. When I deploy this application in a standard servlet container it works. But when I start it using an embedded server it does not recognize the JNDI resources that are present in the context files.

I tried adding the context file to the embeddedTomcatContainer programatically by using the following code. Referred from this [blog](https://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/embedded-tomcat-tips-tricks-and-hacks/) -

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();

            Context context = new StandardContext();
            File f = new File("D:\\Workspace\\SpringBoot\\src\\main\\webapp\\META-INF\\context.xml");


            try {
                context.setConfigFile(f.toURI().toURL());
                tomcat.getHost().addChild(context);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
```

But I'm getting the following Exception. Can someone please let me know how to add context.xml files to embedded tomcat server ?

```
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@100862e: startup date [Mon Nov 23 17:21:38 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-11-23 17:21:39.811  INFO 69992 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-11-23 17:21:39.822  INFO 69992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-11-23 17:21:39.822  INFO 69992 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2015-11-23 17:21:39.842 ERROR 69992 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[null]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_85]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[null]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getObjectKeyPropertiesNameOnly(StandardContext.java:6247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getObjectNameKeyProperties(StandardContext.java:6228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:882) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 7 common frames omitted

2015-11-23 17:21:39.982  INFO 69992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-11-23 17:21:39.982  INFO 69992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1413 ms
2015-11-23 17:21:40.122  INFO 69992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-11-23 17:21:40.122  INFO 69992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-11-23 17:21:40.152 ERROR 69992 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:337) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:452) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.ln.risk.boot.LnBootApplication$1.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(LnBootApplication.java:74) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:167) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.ln.risk.boot.LnBootApplication.main(LnBootApplication.java:39) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2015-11-23 17:21:40.152  WARN 69992 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2015-11-23 17:21:40.152  INFO 69992 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/Workspaces/SpringBoot/ln-boot/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.3/jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.3/jackson-annotations-2.6.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.3/jackson-core-2.6.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.28.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/8.0.28/tomcat-dbcp-8.0.28.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-juli-8.0.28.jar, file:/C:/Users/221008/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar]
2015-11-23 17:21:40.152 ERROR 69992 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.ln.risk.boot.LnBootApplication.main(LnBootApplication.java:39) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:452) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.ln.risk.boot.LnBootApplication$1.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(LnBootApplication.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:167) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:337) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried some more tomcat APIs to load the context.xml file (which has several JNDI Resources and Environments defined) to the embedded server instance, but I keep getting a Null Pointer Exception. PFB the different APIs that I tried to use.

```
1.  tomcat.addContext("/my-boot", System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml");

2.  StandardContext context = new StandardContext();
context.setDefaultContextXml(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml");
tomcat.getHost().addChild(context);
```

For both the approaches I'm getting a NullPointerException while tomcat is trying to get the name of my resource. By the name of the API methods, I feel that there should be a way to get this done. Please assist with this.

```
2015-11-25 11:35:01.441  INFO 74428 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2015-11-25 11:35:01.471  WARN 74428 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl  : Failed to create MBean for naming resource [null]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javax.management.ObjectName.quote(ObjectName.java:1833) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createObjectName(MBeanUtils.java:371) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createMBean(MBeanUtils.java:159) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.initInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6261) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_85]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_85]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866691/springboot-read-tomcat-context-xml - We can refer this question on how to do

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();

            Context context = new StandardContext();
                File file = new File("D:\\Workspace\\SpringBoot\\src\\main\\webapp\\META-INF\\context.xml");
    System.out.println("File Location: "+file.exists());
    //First check for file path is true or not. "file.exists()" method will check the location and return true or flase


            try {
                context.setConfigFile(f.toURI().toURL());
                tomcat.getHost().addChild(context);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer with configureContext seeems to work better for me:

```
import org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig;

@Override
protected void configureContext(Context context, ServletContextInitializer[] initializers) {
    File f = new File("D:\\Workspace\\SpringBoot\\src\\main\\webapp\\META-INF\\context.xml");
    try {
        context.setConfigFile(f.toURI().toURL());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ContextConfig config = new ContextConfig();
    context.addLifecycleListener(config);

    super.configureContext(context, initializers);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Could you try something like this,importing your embedded tomcat context.xml as a resource :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .showBanner(false)
                .sources(Application.class)
                .run(args);
}

@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}
```

**EDIT :** However,the above implementation would require Spring XSD's to parse through the xml document manually as we are trying to customize reading the embedded container.

So,it is always better to go configuring java way for customizing embedded configurations of context.xml ,here is the spring boot doc reference for something like that :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container

Or if you would just want to use the jndi,you could refer to something like [this](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The @ImportResource annotation is trying to import the context.xml file as a Spring Resource, but I dont think the schema of tomcat's context.xml file will be understood by Spring. So I'm getting XML Parse exceptions. This context XML should be directly loaded into tomcat instance.

Comment: Adding resources into Tomcat's JNDI by overriding the postProcessContext(Context context) method works, but we have more than 50 context resources and environments defined in our context.xml file. So before taking that approach, I would like to know if it is feasible to load the context.xml file to embedded tomcat instace.

Comment: Added the edit,please revert back if further queries.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I hope I should go the java way. But I was researching more on Tomcat's EmbeddedServletContainer API and I could see some methods that could be useful for adding a context.xml file. I haven't succeeded with that yet. I will edit my question to post the issue that I'm facing while trying to use tomcat's API.

Comment: @SanjaySSN Did you find any solution to add context.xml in embedded tomcat?

Comment: `@ImportResource` adds a spring configuration file where beans are defined. Not the tomcat configuration file.