# springboot read tomcat-context.xml

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, junit

Hi we got a spring application running on tomcat application-server. I want to add integration tests with Springboot in JUnit. I now got the problem that the embedded tomcat server does not store our datasource and therefore it cannot be looked up... If the server configuration does not have a datasource defined we got a fallback "context.xml" in our resources that should be used. But the embedded tomcat is not reading this configuration and I just cannot figure out, how to do this. 
The following is the point of failure in my JUnit Test, since it cannot find this JNDI-Name in the embedded tomcat:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()
{
  return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("jdbc/myDB");
}
```

the fallback context.xml looks like this:

```
<Context>
<!-- HSQL -->
   <Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
             url="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mymemdb;shutdown=true" username="SA" password=""
             maxTotal="100" maxIdle="5" maxWaitMillis="10000"/>

   <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

how can I push this file into the embedded tomcat on startup?

Comment: By default, JNDI is disabled in embedded Tomcat . This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941829/how-to-create-jndi-context-in-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-container

Answer (score 4):

Spring Boot offer many ways to [externalize your configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)...

You can define your [datasource properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) in your `tomcat/conf/Catalina/<host>` context descriptors.

You could define your jndi name:

```
<Context>
    <Parameter name="spring.datasource.jndi-name" value="/pathToYourDatasource" />
</Context>
```

Or define the datasource:

```
<Context>
    <Parameter name="spring.datasource.url" value="your url" />
    <Parameter name="spring.datasource.username" value="your username" />
    <Parameter name="spring.datasource.password" value="your password" />
</Context>
```

Even define the path to an `application.properties` and set here your configuration:

```
<Context>
    <Parameter name="spring.config.location" value="/path/to/application.properties" />
</Context>
```

This way is not necessary set programmatically your hardcoded datasource and you can put another database configuration for testing in `src/test/resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

Comment: Its bit late I know, but could you please explain where to put the file with content     
    `<Context>...</Context>`, in order to get the JNDI resource loaded in the embedded tomcat?

Comment: @Manu we put context details in web.xml or context.xml