# Set application.properties value from JNDI Environment value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, jndi, spring-rabbit

I am building a spring boot application, that has RabbitMQ configuration like below.

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=host
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=userName
spring.rabbitmq.password=password
```

I need to set environment specific configuration. But that configuration needs to be read from tomcat context.xml file.
I would need to pass the values for host, username, and password by reading from tomcat Environment tag set in context.xml.

How can I do this?

Spring docs says: [24.3 Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

> If your application runs in a container, then JNDI properties (in java:comp/env) or servlet context initialization parameters can be used instead of, or as well as, environment variables or system properties.

can they be directly used like this:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host="${rabbitMQHost}"
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=${rabbitMQUserName}
spring.rabbitmq.password=${rabbitMQPassword}
```

Comment: Not with the double quotes as you've used in `spring.rabbitmq.host="${rabbitMQHost}"`

Comment: @N00b Pr0grammer, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check if this helps @Rax -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866691/springboot-read-tomcat-context-xml